# Can't understand console error: 'Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, google-maps-react

I am attempting to host a Ruby on Rails / React app in Heroku. Also of not, I am using the package google-maps-react ( https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react ). Everything works locally, but when I push to heroku, nothing displays, and this error appears in console:

```
windowOrGlobal.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
    at Object.a (windowOrGlobal.js:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (windowOrGlobal.js:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index-fb4bbac5de0de29c6900.js:2)
    at n (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ScriptCache.js:3)
    at n (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (GoogleApiComponent.js:5)
    at n (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:5)
    at n (bootstrap:19)
```

When I click on the top line from the error stack, it is this:

```
var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && _typeof(Symbol.iterator) === "symbol" ? function (obj) {
```

Where is `t` being attempted to be called as a function? I can't figure out where that error could be coming from, when there is nothing attempting to call a function `t()`.

Anyone have any clue what might be going on?

Comment: You can't use a function expression in the same expression that declares it. For example `var x = x(1) ? function(){} : function(){};` Will give `TypeError: x is not a function`. I'm guessing the explaination the you're getting `t` and not `_typeof  is not a function` is obfuscation.

Comment: The [same line from the repo](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/85031c590eeae57e2383c3de3e8c4c21568191c8/dist/lib/windowOrGlobal.js#L16) reads `var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) {`. Which is correctly using the `typeof` keyword.

Comment: @max ah I see, thank you very much! This is coming from an npm package so I'm not sure how to fix it. I can maybe push a PR to the package or something right?

Comment: This looks a lot like [known issue 35501](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35501). Check out [this solution](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35501#issuecomment-555312633)

Comment: @JaredBeck holy shit that worked lol, thank you very much!

Comment: @muceyMuce - It would be great if you can post the solution to your problem as an answer and mark it as accepted so that it helps others facing the same issue.